# Is it possible to use a website's site-key to generate a valid token?

Tags: web-scraping, recaptcha

I think that the title is pretty self-explanatory to what i'm asking, but i'll elaborate anyways. Basically, in recaptcha's there are specific site-keys (presumably unique to each site). With the services like 2captcha, they require said site-key. This is where my question comes in. Basically, is it possible to make a barebones website (only containing recaptcha element thing) and switch out your site-key for another website's and generate a valid token that can be copy/pasted over into the other website and it functions? I really don't understand recaptcha's all too well, so sorry in advance if this is just "dumb".

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do this in most cases. When you [create a reCAPTCHA site key for a website](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key#create-key) it is suggested to specify a Domain List enumerating which website(s) are protected by this key. If you try to create a token from a different website it will be considered invalid. This is deliberately set up to protect against the exact exploit you are describing.